# Why is the Controls section not present in the Developer tab for Excel Workbook Project in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012

Why is the Controls section not present in the Developer tab for Excel Workbook Project in Visual Studio 2012?

When I open Excel 2010 the Developer tab contains the Controls section:

[image]

But in my Excel 2010 Workbook project the Developer tab is present, but the Controls section is not there.
Not sure what is the problem?

Thanks